# How to bias a common source amplifier?

Tags: mosfet, amplifier

its been a while since I did anything with mosfets and completely forgot how to do anything basic anymore with them. I was wondering if anyone can lead me back on the right path.

For the past week I tried finding examples of how to bias a common source configuration however, in almost every practice question I find they give you pretty much all the information such as ID, Kn, etc like here:
[image]

I would think that designing an amplifier ID (Drain Current) would be a variable that you would need to find through your design spec.

and when reading the IV-Characteristics curve I am totally lost. I get you want to pick a point in the saturation region so you can exercise your full voltage swings but how does one find the correct VGS and ID and VDS to do this?

Another question about the IV Curve. When you do find your specific point, and let say its at ID = 20mA and VGS = 5V, VDS = 10V does this mean the mosfet will provide 20mA and the drop across VDS will be 10V? or is the mosfet capable of allowing 20mA through the drain? If so is this constant across all voltage supplis and not invalidating ohms law?

The way I think things are done are as so (Not having an RE/RS resistor 
VS = 0):

Design Spec
P = 20W output
RL = 8ohm (Speaker load)

1. Use the power equation to see how much voltage I need at the output and that will determine my power supply.
2. Find the transfer function of the CS Amplifier then solve for RD to find my desire gain I need (However how do I find my Gm, and ro value?)
3. then I guess I have enough to find my ID? and from here I guess I iterate different values to where i want to be in the saturation region?

Comment: You are better off biasing with Rdg and Rg-in for gain and bias. Then boost with Rs bypass cap, but your load and power specs are unreasonable.

Comment: Those design was for example sake. It was more so the process.

Comment: Not practical topology ... nor is this but more fun http://tinyurl.com/vr73vya

Comment: Besides the unrealistic values, there's still valid questions within the post, such as how does one read an IV-Curve, how to bias a mosfet, where to bias a mosfet in the saturation region etc etc. For example how did you get that mosfet in saturation in that simulator